# Storing social network app credentials in XBMC plugin code

Tags: python, twitter, obfuscation, xbmc, kodi

I'm working on an <del>XBMC</del> Kodi plugin that uses parts of the Twitter API. This means that I have to store my Twitter app credentials (consumer key, secret, ...) in the plugin's code.

Now, as Kodi plugins are distributed as sourcecode, this means that my Twitter app credentials are there for anyone to see (and use).

Two questions:

1. Is this in fact a problem?
2. If so, is there any way I can hide or obfuscate my keys?